# How to setup a Dockerfile with your git repo?

Tags: git, docker, github

Some git repositories have a Dockerfile.
The user can  type:

```
sudo docker build -t opensfm https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM.git
```

The docker begins to build.

How is this done?

When we put the same Dockerfile in a repository and attempt to build it:

```
docker build -t exchange https://github.com/atursams/exchange.git
```

we get:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error fetching: fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
```

Comment: Looks like the command pulls master branch by default and now default branch is `main` in github

Comment: Typically with a GitHub project you'd `git clone` it to your local system, and then you can `sudo docker build .`.  Does this workflow work for your use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is "cannot find remote ref master", and indeed, your repository has no `master` branch. Fortunately, this situation is addressed [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories); just include the branch name as part of the URL:

```
docker build -t exchange https://github.com/atursams/exchange.git#main
```

Also, your repository doesn't currently have a `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository does not contain a branch named "master" (your is named main)